# Why is the SD card from a D800 not readable under Windows 10?

Tags: sdcard, nikon-d800, windows-10

I have a Nikon Z 50 and, just like it happened with the previous D7100 and D40, the SD card I use in it is readable under Windows 10 by using a normal SD card reader. The same happens with other cameras using the same physical SD card.

The SD card (maybe SDHC, surely not SDXC) is a Sandisk 8 GB from some years ago, rated about 45-60 MB/s so not the cheapest series back then (and still today).

That same card formatted on the Z 50 is not recognised by a D800 (firmware A/B 1.10) and, once formatted in the D800, is not readable at all under Windows 10, which only sees in Disk manager the presence of a partition, but not the type of partition and obviously not the content. It does not even appear in "My computer" as unreadable, which is often the case when a wrong disk format is used (like a card formatted for linux or Mac).

I am forced to use a USB cable to download photos from the D800.

Why is that? how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does it show in the [disk management](https://winaero.com/find-file-system-drive-windows-10/)?

Comment: I wouldn't use the same card in different devices. Cards are not overly expensive. (Try buying film!) Of course a card used in a D800 should be readable in Windows 10. Many, many users don't experience the same problem. If you are experiencing any issues with a memory card, I wouldn't trust it. I'd suggest considering it to have reached end-of-life and just buy a new card.

Comment: Also, you mention a "normal SD card reader". Are you sure the card reader is functioning reliably?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#File_system), SD cards are formatted with  well-known variants of the FAT filesystem, so a working card out of your Z50 should be readable, unless 1) the card (or reader) is marginal (try a diffefrent card/reader), or 2) you unknowingly enabled some "security" feature (the "S" in "SD"). Also, if the Z50 cards were normally not readable under Windows a Google search would show other people asking the question...

Comment: @xenoid yes it shows with a partition of unknown type. The cards formatted in the Z50 are perfectly visible. It could be that the Z50 uses exfat and the D800 not, but the issue was also that the card formatted in the D800 was not visible under W10.

Comment: @osullic the card is working fine with other cameras. The reader is used all the time with other cards as well.

Comment: If you have a linux machine at hand and know how to use it, there are plenty of tools available to investigate the situation...

Answer (score 1):

The card must have used a partition table which the D800 couldn't read, since I tried now to format it using Rufus as MBR/FAT32 and the D800 can read it without issues.